# pandas dataframe copy of slice warning

Tags: python, pandas

I'm fairly new to pandas, and was getting the infamous SettingWithCopyWarning in a large piece of code. I boiled it down to the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,3],[3,3],[3,1],[1,1]], columns=list('AB'))
df
df = df.loc[(df.A>1) & (df.B>1)]
df['B'] = 10
```

When I run this I get the warning:

**main**:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

The strange thing is that if I leave off the "df" line it runs without a warning. Is this intended behavior?

In general, if I want to filter a DataFrame by the values across various columns, do I need to do a copy() to avoid the SettingWithCopyWarning?

thanks very much

Comment: My question is why am I getting a warning at all. Unless you always have to use the .copy() when you're getting a subset of a DataFrame

Comment: @ errg see my answer and the page i referred that will help i beleive.

Comment: another [link on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) with the great details ...

Comment: hese two chained operations execute independently, one after another. The first is an access method (get operation), that will return a DataFrame containing all rows at column A & B atr >1 .
The second is an assignment operation (set operation), that is called on this new DataFrame with the changed data. We are not operating on the original DataFrame at all rather ob changed dataset

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guess the point is that when I've done: df = df.loc[(df.A>1) & (df.B>1)], even though I've thrown away the original DataFrame, df is still considered to be a slice into it, and I need to explicitly do a copy if I want to modify it.

Comment: Okay, hope you will get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DataFrame as below from your question, this will avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning`

There is [github Discussion](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11984) and solution suggested by one of the Pandas developer Jeff :)

```
df
   A  B
1  3  3
```

Best to use this way.

```
df['B'] = df['B'].replace(3, 10)
df
   A   B
1  3  10
```

Comment: But this is kind of a crazy length to go to - you have to know what the previous value was (3) in order to replace it with a 10.

Comment: @KenWilliams, yes its indeed.